# Center a background image in Report Viewer 2010

Tags: background-image, reportviewer, visual-studio-2012

Apart from resizing the image, is there a way to center a background image in report viewer? It seems I can make it repeat, clip, but not center, which is the only thinkg I want to do with it.

Comment: That property is surprisingly missing / hard to find.